# Is there any opensourse set of components or some framework for creating Flex mxml graphs (Node-based UIs)?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, graph, mxml

Is there any opensourse, free set of components for creating Flex mxml graphs?

like aviary [Peacock](https://web.archive.org/web/20131122100328/http://aviary.com:80/tools/peacock) style ones

[image]
<sub>(source: [peacockwiki at sites.google.com](https://sites.google.com/site/peacockwiki/_/rsrc/1249407903775/Home/1p.png))</sub>

with at least Drag, drop, and connect generators

so each graph element could have

[image]
<sub>(source: [peacockwiki at sites.google.com](https://sites.google.com/site/peacockwiki/_/rsrc/1235963529364/Home/peacock-overview/Hub1.png))</sub>

or something like that.

Framework should be opensource (like GPL, LGPL etc)

**BTW**: I found [one wary bacic](https://web.archive.org/web/20111006213224/http://www.finflex.fi:80/projects/degrafaProcessMap/) made by Erno Aapa with [Degrafa](https://www.degrafa.org/) but I would really love to see something much more **Flex 4 - mxml oriented** and frienfdly.

So blog articles, Google code projects, anything - please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a specific answer for you; but just some places to go look.

Have you looked at the Advanced Charting and Visualization package from Adobe? They are part of the open source SDK with the release of Flex 4.

You already mentioned [Degra](http://degrafa.org/).  I understood that Degrafa stands for Declarative Graphics.  I'm surprised you'd say it is not MXML friendly.

Have you looked at [Axiss](http://www.axiis.org/)?  It is another project out there, and I believe it relies heavily on Degrafa.

You said open source, but didn't say free.  So, I believe source code is available if you purchase a license to [iLog](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/visualization/elixir/).  I'm not sure about [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/), but I've heard very positive things about it from other Flex Developers.

Comment: I ment not Degrafa but that sample I mentioned - It is not so easy to undestend...

Answer (score 0):

[Moccasin](http://code.google.com/p/moccasin/) and [Flex Wires](http://github.com/joshtynjala/flexwires) combined should get you most of the way there.

Comment: so... Could you give an example of how to create simple graph editor with it (at least with functions shown in Erno Aapa saple (connect, disconect elements)?)

Comment: I don't have any examples, but those two projects should be a good head start :)